# Strange disk space utilization by collections in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I have 2 collections (edge collection) and both have similar type of data. Each have around 400k documents. But one of the collection occupies more than double of the disk space. I am wondering why it is like that. I do a lot of update/replace. Could it be because arangodb keeps all the revisions? 90% space is occupied by datafiles. If it's because of the revisions how can I disable persisting the revisions.

Comment: By looking at 'figures' I see that Dead documents size is huge. How can I disable saving dead documents?

Comment: doCompact is set to false by the way

Comment: ArangoDB keeps [revisions](https://docs.arangodb.com/Documents/DocumentAddress.html) for [MVCC](https://docs.arangodb.com/AdministratingArango/index.html), but the reason could also be the [quadratic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost) of datafiles. For example, if 512MB of allocated space are exceeded, the size is doubled to 1024MB, even if only 513MB are actually needed. One of your collections might be currently at 511MB, the other slightly over 512MB causing the latter to be twice the size.

Comment: I have 469964  documents with 148 mb disk for Alive and 7805222 documents with 2.4 gb for dead documents.
    
How can I disable the revisions. doCompact was set to false because we ran into a performance issue because of this where disk i/o was constantantly heavy.

Comment: Setting `doCompact` to `false` will actually cause the old revisions of the documents to be kept forever in the datafiles. Setting it to `true` will start the cleanup process in that collection. The cleanup is performed by a background thread and will run interleaved with the other operations in that collection. It will potentially rewrite all the datafiles of the collection if most data are from dead documents. The end result should be much less disk usage if most of the documents in the datafiles are dead revisions.

Comment: you could use a [task](https://docs.arangodb.com/ModuleTasks/index.html) to enable / disable compaction during times when your system is expected to be idle.

Comment: Setting `doCompact` to `true` has performance issues. `dispat_def` threads takes up a lot of cpu and my foxx app performance degrades from few seconds to minutes. It would nicer to `disable the revision` at all (if I m never gonna use that feature ) !!

Comment: Also, `lsof | grep deleted` shows me 3k opened deleted files like this `[v8-gc]    1209 1238   arangodb  DEL       REG              202,1               526156 /var/lib/arangodb/databases/database-96641/collection-39763320/deleted-39959928.db
` and it consumes all my 30 GB disk space.

Comment: The `dispat_def` thread has nothing to do with compaction and revision handling. `dispat_def` is used to execute HTTP requests and periodic tasks from queues. Revision handling cannot be disabled even if not used explicitly. This is because ArangoDB will never overwrite an existing document in a disk file but instead append the new revision to the file. Among other things, this allows readers to read the old version while a new version is available. The compaction is there to remove the unused revisions later when they aren't used anymore. Turning it off will lead to ever-increasing disk usage

Comment: I tried to reproduce it with a quick test and failed. Concerning the code in question for closing datafiles, do you see any warnings in your logfiles like that: 'munmap failed with ...' or 'closing an already closed datafile' ? It seems that the munmap() system call can fail if the filesytstem is full; In general the only way to resolve this condition is to restart arangod so it releases the filedescriptors.

Comment: Yes, restarting arangod resolves a lot of issues.

Comment: Since we don't know how to reproduce this, can we close this issue? In general Githup seems to be more appropriate for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the compactor thread is intended to clean up unused WAL-files. This was already done by ArangoDB. Thus the files using the space weren't shown in `ls` anymore.

The situation was caused by disabling the compactor thread to save system performance, thus many files were released at once.

However, for some reason arangod didn't close the file handles, which resulted in the file system not releasing the space of the deleted files.

This could be resolved by restarting the ArangoDB daemon - on shut down the held file handles were closed and the space released.

Meanwhile the issue of non-closing WAL-files has been fixed and is available as of ArangoDB 2.8.6